# Как скрестить сервер Dell CS24-SC и одиночный SSD?

Tags: hdd, ssd, dell

Суть такова, имеем сервер DELL CS24-SC, в нем рейд-контроллер LSI SAS 3000 
Стоит в рейде 2 диска HDD по 250 гиг, и есть желание либо заменить их на один SSD Samsung 860PRO 
или добавить его как отдельный, но в упор не видит их контроллер.
Но все попытки его обнаружить заканчиваются неудачей.
Уже и ставил его отдельно и третьим и выключал вообще LSI контролер - и ничего, не видит его хоть убейся.

Есть подозрение что вообще сервер старый и не увидит его, хотя если его вставляешь, то при загрузке LSI выдает сообщение

> WARNING! Foreign Metadata detected...

Comment: Что-то не нахожу я модели LSI SAS 3000. Вы уверены? В любом случае, раз контроллер определяет `Foreign Metadata`, то диск он все же видит, просто его нужно доконфигурировать. Смотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Нужно очистить `Foreign Metadata`.

Зайдите на сервере в OpenManage -> Information/Configuration tab -> Controller Tasks -> Foreign Configuration Operations -> Execute. В следующем окошке - Clear. SSD должен появиться в списке физических дисков.

Comment: После инсталяции OpenManage не могу залогиниться. Пишет Login failed....connection error. Кажется мне, что нет там DELL EMC. Модель ---  Device Description
1) LSILOGIC Logical Volume SCSI Disk Device
2) LSI Adapter, SAS 3000 series, 4-port with 1064E
3) Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller

Comment: Если Вы заходите под Windows, то следует использовать аккаунт с правами локального администратора на сервере. Используйте Internet Explorer, добавьте сервер в Intranet зону и отключите IE Security Config

Comment: я захожу через Microsoft Remode Desktop c с правами администратора. Получаю урл в IE типа такого https://win-f64avendk69:1311/OMSALogin?msgStatus=null. Там ввожу IP (пробовал IP  192.168.88.151 и 127.0.0.1 сервера и Administrator и пароль. И постоянно ошибка = Login failed....
connection error

Comment: нет каких-то других вариантов как поставить этот OpenManage?